# How do I prove this seemingly obvious property of subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

The statement is the following: Given an abelian group $G=\langle a_1,...,a_t\rangle$, and a subgroup $H$ of $G$, we need at most $t$ elements to generate $H$; i.e. $H=\langle b_1,...,b_t\rangle$ for some $b_1,...,b_t\in H$.
While this statement seems obvious I couln't find a way to prove it, even if I limited myself to finite groups. I tried a couple of approaches (see below). Any help will be appreciated.

---

**Approach 1:** I tried proving that if $\{ [a_1]_H,...,[a_k]_H\}$ is a minimal generating set for $G/H$, and $\{ b_1,...,b_t\}$ is a minimal generating set for $H$, then $\{ a_1,...,a_k,b_1,...,b_t\}$ is a minimal generating set for $G$.

---

**Approach 2:** Limiting myself to finite groups, I tried proving the statement using induction. I tried induction on the size of $G$, size of $H$, and size of the minimal sets generating $G$ and $H$.

Comment: How about considering the smallest powers $n_i$ of the $a_1, \ldots , a_t$ such that  $a_i^{n_i} \in H$?

Comment: It's not obvious, and it is not true for nonabelian groups. Use induction on $t$. It's true for $t=1$ when $G$ is cyclic. For $t>1$, let $K$ be the subgroup $\langle a_2,\ldots,a_t \rangle$ of $G$. Then by induction, $H \cap K$ can be generated by $t-1$ elements, and $H/H \cap K \cong HK/K \le G/K$, which is cyclic, so $H/H \cap K$ needs only one generator, and you are done.

Comment: I don't think it is obvious at all. One way to do it is to start following the proof of the classification theorem for finitely generated abelian groups. That is, write the embedding of $H$ into $G$ in matrix form, and then apply row and column elementary operations until you get a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @sqtrat Consider the subgroup of $\mathbb Z^2$ defined by $H=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb Z^2|x+y\in2\mathbb Z\}.$ Then the smallest powers are $2$ in both the $X$ and $Y$ direction but the elements $(2,0)$ and $(0,2)$ do not generate $H.$

Comment: @DerekHolt I'm willing to accept that as an answer, if you just elaborate a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already had a proof of this written down, so I have copied and pasted it.

Let $K \le G$ with $G$ an (additive) abelian group generated by $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. We shall prove by induction on $n$ that $K$ can be generated
by at most $n$ elements. If $n=1$ then $G$ is cyclic and hence so
is $K$.  Suppose $n>1$, and let $H$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by
$x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}$. By induction, $K \cap H$ is generated by
$y_1,\ldots,y_{m-1}$, say, with $m \le n$. If $K \le H$, then  $K = K \cap H$
and we are done, so suppose not.

Then there exist elements of the form $h +  t x_n \in K$ with
$h \in H$ and $t \ne 0$. Since $-(h+t x_n) \in K$, we can assume that
$t > 0$. Choose such an element  $y_m = h +  t x_n \in K$
with $t$ minimal subject to $t > 0$.
We claim that $K$ is generated by $y_1,\ldots,y_m$, which will complete the
proof. Let $k \in K$. Then $k = h' + u x_n$ with $h' \in H$ and $u \in {\mathbb Z}$.
If $t$ does not divide $u$ then we can write $u = tq + r$ with $q,r \in {\mathbb Z}$
and $0 < r < t$, and then $k - qy_m = (h'-qh) + rx_n \in K$, contrary to
the choice of $t$. So $t|u$ and hence $u=tq$ and $k - qy_m \in K \cap H$.
But $K \cap H$ is generated by $y_1,\ldots,y_{m-1}$, so we are done.